# Sinatra exits without error

Tags: ruby, sinatra, assets

I'm very new to Sinatra, and I'm trying to get asset management & compiling working according to [this article](http://recipes.sinatrarb.com/p/asset_management/sinatra_assetpack#label-Sinatra-Assetpack). Here is my main file so far:

```
require 'sinatra/base'
require 'sinatra/assetpack'
require 'sass'

class App < Sinatra::Base
  register Sinatra::AssetPack
  assets do

    css :application, [
      '/css/main.scss'
    ]

    css_compression :sass

  end


  get '/hi' do
    erb "Hello World!"
  end
end
```

but, for some reason, when I run `ruby main.rb`, it just exits without failure or anything. Is there a special keyword to get the application to serve files?

Comment: Have you setup a config.ru file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the modular style of Sinatra application, as you are doing, running `ruby main.rb` is going to exit without error because it is being treated as a standard ruby application and no webserver is ever created.

You have two options.

1 Add `run! if app_file == $0` just before the final `end` statement in your example.
    This will allow you to run the app with `ruby main.rb`

2 (This is the preferred method) Create a rackup file `config.ru` with the following contents.

```
require './main.rb'
run App
```

Now you can serve the application with the command `rackup -p 4567` where 4567 is whatever port number you want to use.

Answer (score 0):

You need to [start the application](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html#Serving%20a%20Modular%20Application)

```
require 'sinatra/base'
require 'sinatra/assetpack'
require 'sass'

class App < Sinatra::Base
  register Sinatra::AssetPack
  assets do

    css :application, [
      '/css/main.scss'
    ]

    css_compression :sass

  end


  get '/hi' do
    erb "Hello World!"
  end

  run! if app_file == $0
end
```

Answer (score 0):

one observation, erb should point to a template, example:

```
get '/hi' do
  erb :home
end
```

should look for a file in ../views/home.erb

Also Assuming you already did `gem install sinatra`. I would also use the rerun gem while developing in sinatra, `gem install rerun` then `rerun ruby app.rb`. Rerun will reload your project when you make changes to your code so you won't have to restart the app when ever you make a change.

Comment: This is a bit off topic from the original post, but to be clear, the `template` that is passed into `erb` can be a string, it does not need to point to a `.erb` file as you are indicating here.